# Why does one Android phone automatically save pictures while another one doesn't?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-camera-intent

I'm running the same app on two different phones. One phone is a ZTE Maven (Android 5.1) and the other is a Google Pixel 2 (Android 10).

The Android 5.1 phone automatically saves pictures taken with the camera (via an Intent) to the Gallery. However, the Android 10 phone does not save the pictures to Photos (there's no Gallery app).

My app uses Xamarin.Forms, and here's the relevant code:

```
public class CameraService : ICameraService
{
    public Task<Stream> TakePhotoAsync()
    {
        var dir = MainActivity.Instance.ApplicationContext.FilesDir;
        var imageFile = new File(dir, $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.jpg");
        MainActivity.Instance.PhotoPath = imageFile.Path;

        var imageUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(MainActivity.Instance,
            "com.(company).(appname).android.fileprovider", imageFile);

        var intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
        intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, imageUri);

        // Start the camera capture activity (resumes in MainActivity.cs)
        MainActivity.Instance.StartActivityForResult(
            intent, MainActivity.TakePhotoId);

        // Save the TaskCompletionSource object as a MainActivity property
        MainActivity.Instance.TakePhotoTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Stream>();

        // Return Task object
        return MainActivity.Instance.TakePhotoTaskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
}
```

Obviously, I've replaced the real company and app names with "(company)" and "(appname)".

Is there any reason these phones or Android versions behave differently in terms of saving the pictures internally? Is there any way I could tell whether this auto-save will happen?

Comment: As usual you should inform the media store about the new file. So let your file be scanned. Rebooting the device will do too.

Comment: Maybe the picture hasn't been updated yet,you could try to call  `MediaStore.Images.Media.InsertImage` method after you take photo.